# RDS installation failure on 2012 R2 Server Core VM in Hyper-V Server

Tags: powershell, terminal-server, windows-server-2012-r2, rds, windows-server-core

I'm currently installing a test-bed for my firms Infrastructure replacement.
10 or so Windows/Linux servers will be replaced by 2 physical servers running Hyper-V server. All services (DC, RDS, SQL) will be on Windows 2012 R2 Server Core VMs, Exchange on Server 2012 R2 GUI, and the rest are things like Elastix, MailArchiver etc, which aren't part of the equation thus far.

I have installed Hyper-V server on a test box, and sucessfully got two virtual DC's running, SQL 2014 running, and 8.1 which I use for the RSAT tools.
When trying to install RDS (The old fashioned kind, not the newer VDI(?) style), I get a failed installation due to the server not being able to reboot. A couple of articles have said not to do it locally, so I've moved on.

Using PowerShell, I run the following commands from any Server within the network, on the RDS server:

Import-Module RemoteDesktop

New-SessionDeployment -ConnectionBroker "AlstersTS.Alsters.local" -SessionHost "AlstersTS.Alsters.local"

The installation begins, carries on for 2 or 3 minutes, then I receive the following error message:

New-SessionDeployment : Validation failed for the "RD Connection Broker" parameter.
AlstersTS.Alsters.local     Unable to connect to the server by using WindowsPowerShell remoting. Verify that you can connect to the server.
At line:1 char:1
+ NewSessionDeployment -ConnectionBroker "AlstersTS.Alsters.local" -SessionHost " ...
+
    + CategoryInfo      : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorID : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,New-SessionDeployment

So far, I have:

1. Triple, triple checked syntax.
2. Tried various other commands, and a script to accomplish the same task.
3. Checked DNS is functioning as it should.
4. Checked to the best of my knowledge that AD is working as it should.
5. Checked that the Network Service has the needed permissions.
6. Created another VM and placed the two roles on different servers.
7. Deleted all VMs, started again with a new domain name (Lather, rinse, repeat)
8. Performed the whole installation on a second physical box running Hyper-V Server
9. Pleaded with it

Interestingly, if I perform the installation via a GUI installation, the thing just works! Now I know I could convert this to a Server Core role after installation, but this wouldn't teach me what was wrong in the first instance.

I've probably got 10 pages through various Google searches, each page getting a little less relevant. The closest matches seem to have good information, but it doesn't seem to be the fix for my set-up.

As a side note, I expected to be able to "tee" or "out-file" the error message into a text file, but couldn't get that to work either, so I've typed in the error message manually.

Chaps, any suggestions, from the glaringly obvious, to the long-winded and complex?

Thanks!

Comment: `1.` Why would you install the RDS Role on a DC or a SQL server? `2.` AFAIK, RDS isn't a supported Role in a Server Core install.

Comment: Hello, a misunderstanding I think. I was using the DC and the SQL server to remotely access the RDS server. None of the servers will be sharing any roles.

Comment: Under 2012 R2, RDS should be supported on Server Core.

Comment: I've re-written a portion of the question to emphasise it's a command being run on the DC/SQL directed to the RDS server.

Comment: `AlstersTS.Alsters.local Unable to connect to the server by using WindowsPowerShell remoting.` Were you able to confirm that powershell remoting is working? If you run `Enter-PSSession -ComputerName AlstersTS.Alsters.local` does it work?